Why do I receive non-zero Euler angle orientation when I plug-in the IMU?
I have Parker Lord 3DMGX5-AHRS IMU. When I plug-in the device and run its ros node to get the values on the IMU topic, i get the orientation, angular velocity, acceleration, magnetic field values. Then, I convert the quarternion to euler angles using transformation library. My question is why do I receive non-zero orientation values when I plug it in specific orientation? With respect to what frame is it reporting the orientation values?
My aim is to update the heading value of my robot initially found using GPS by updating with the yaw value from IMU since the IMU's XY axis is parallel to the robot's base always and X point towards the robot's front. Do I need to do any tilt correction if the robot is on an incline?
